# Probability of Ace of Spades in Monty Hall Like Scenario

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I select a card at random from a standard deck of playing cards.

The probability of this card being the Ace of Spades is 1/52.

From the remaining cards, someone turns over all but one, and none of these is the Ace of spades. This person is aware of which card is which and has deliberately avoided turning over the Ace of Spades.

Why is the probability that the remaining card is the Ace of Spades 51/52?

Specifically, how can I understand this in terms of the basic formula for probability?

$\frac{\text{no. successful outcomes}}{\text{no. possible outcomes}}$

Even though I know that since the original card has a 1/52 chance and all the possible outcomes must sum to a probability of 1, this is not convincing me at the moment, and I want to understand the result in terms of what "is" happening with the cards, rather than what "isn't".

Please not that this last point makes this question different to the existing similar question here: [Cards Probability like Monty Hall Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501577/cards-probability-like-monty-hall-problem)

Comment: "*Someone turns over all but one, and none of these is the Ace of spades*"  This doesn't make sense to me.  Do they peek at all $51$ and very intentionally turn over any and all who aren't the ace of spades except one of them if it happened to be the ace of spades or except for one of them chosen uniformly at random assuming none of them were the ace of spades?

Comment: The exact behavior and decision process for what cards if an to turn over must be very clearly detailed because a change in understood behavior changes the probabilities.

Comment: They are intentionally avoiding revealing the Ace of Spades, in a way that is analogous to the Monty Hall Problem.

Comment: Just play this game ten or so times with a friend

Comment: So then... if you insist on a "ratio of number of outcomes" style argument... phrase it in the following way:  Choose a card to be the initial "first" card.  Then choose a random number $1$-$51$.  In the event that the first card was the ace of spades, then this second chosen number corresponds to which card was chosen for the other card in the deck as the remaining card.  In the event the first card was not the ace of spades, then this second number is superfluous and doesn't affect the second card drawn, but it still occurs, just to keep things consistent.

Comment: There are $52\times 51$ outcomes.  $1\times 51$ of which correspond to the ace of spades being picked first and $51\times 51$ of which correspond to ace of spades not being picked first, giving the probability as $\dfrac{1\times 51}{52\times 51} = \dfrac{1}{52}$ for having drawn an ace originally and $\dfrac{51\times 51}{52\times 51}=\dfrac{51}{52}$ for having not, thus making what you have the option to switch to being the ace of spades.

Comment: That said, I strongly discourage insisting on only ever using ratio of number of outcomes style arguments since they can be deeply flawed.  You need to make sure that in any such style argument you deal with it must be that outcomes in the sample space are equally likely to occur.  There are two outcomes to the lottery, you win or you lose, but you certainly don't win $\dfrac{1}{2}$ of the time.  It also prevents you from adequately understanding probabilities which involve irrational numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's just note that the formula
$$\frac{\text{no. successful outcomes}}{\text{no. possible outcomes}}$$
applies only to situations in which you can identify a finite number of equally likely outcomes, and is **not** "the basic formula for probability".

Now let's apply it to the cards.

The ace of spades is equally likely to be in any of the $52$ places where a card is located. Of these $52$ places, $51$ are where the "remaining cards" are.

Therefore the chance is $\frac{51}{52}$ that the ace of spades is among the remaining cards.

The procedure of turning over cards is something that a person who knows where the ace is can always do, regardless of whether the ace is in the $51$ remaining cards or is the card you originally chose. The ability to do this procedure tells us nothing about the probability of whether the ace is in the remaining cards.

What turning over the cards does is to tell us, **if** the ace is one of the remaining cards, **which** of the remaining cards it is.
As far as the probability of winning is concerned,
it's really no different than having the opportunity to discard your original card, pick up the remaining $51$ cards in a pile, and if you can find the ace of spades in that pile yourself you win.
Think of it as just a bit of showmanship.